# Transform a "table-data" file in CSV

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a long text file with some "tabular" data, i.e.:

```
12/10/2018  aaaa bbb     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx      002424004234
                         xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                         xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                         xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
12/11/2018 cccc        dddd     yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy      0542121212122
                                yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
12/12/2018 eeee       ffffff   zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz      0639872651252
12/13/2018  ggggggg hhhhhh     vvvvv vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      1968745213648
                               vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
12/14/2018  ....
```

as result of a scan, where some columns are like "cells" of a spreadsheet.
How I can, with some command line tools, transform on CSV file like:

```
12/10/2018,aaaaaaaa,bbbbb,xxxxxx.......xxxx,002424004234
12/11/2018,ccccccc,dddddd,yyyyyy.......yyyy,0542121212122
```

etc.?

Thank you

**EDIT:**
I have a text file as result of a scan of papers. This papers presents data in "tabular manner", i.e. third column is "multi-line" text. I would transform this to a simple CSV file, i.e., in ONE row i would all of text of multiline "cell". xxxxx...xxxx reproduce multiline text of third column

**EDIT2:**
Example of data

```
Date         AMOUNT      OP     DESCRIPTION                                 CODE
12/10/2018   $123,45    id01   payment for hotel in Las Vegas            005214875462     
                              room
                              room service
                              dinner
                              golf club

12/11/2018   $400,00    id04    cash from ATM                            0528158852687
                                 located in L.A.
12/12/2018   $1000,00   id99    ACME tornado pill                         854674852658
```

I would like to transform in

```
12/10/2018;$123,45;id01;payment for hotel in Las Vegas room room service     dinner golf club;005214875462     
12/11/2018;$400,00;id04;cash from ATM located in L.A.;0528158852687
12/12/2018;$1000,00;id99;ACME tornado pill;854674852658
```

Comment: Your question is NOT clear, please add more details in your question and let us know then.

Comment: How are we supposed to know what `xxxxxx.......xxxx` in your output represents from your input? Are some of those spaces blanks and others tabs or something else? Put a bit more thought/effort into creating an example that's unambiguous and truly captures your requirements. Also add what you have tried so far. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: Are you asking how to replace your tab characters with commas?

Comment: Excuse me for my cryptic question.
I have a text file as result of a scan of papers.
This papers presents data in "tabular manner", i.e. third column is "multi-line" text.
I would transform this to a simple CSV file, i.e., in ONE row i would all of text of multiline "cell". xxxxx...xxxx reproduce multiline text of third column

Comment: Don't add information in comments, simply [edit] your question to contain all relevant information, a good example, and make sense stand-alone.

Comment: Please read your question, identify where it's ambiguous, and correct the issues. For example you have `ggggggg hhhhhh     vvvvv vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv` in one input line. Is the first space a blank or a tab? How about the 2nd one? How about the 3rd one? Whiy does that block of `v`s have a space in it or that line have more fields than the rest? Can the blocks of same-chars have spaces? Can they ALL be blanks? Can any of them be tabs? What's the leading space on the lines that don't start with a date - blanks or tabs or a mixture?

Comment: You use `x` as every char in the first block of input - if you used different chars for each row then you could show those chars in the output instead of just all `x`s again leaving us guessing which row(s) they came from. etc., etc... Just **THINK** about how your question reads to someone who isn't you and doesn't know your domain and then correct the issues.

Comment: How about you start over. Add sample data that matches what you are seeing in real life. Note where there is a tab vs space so we can also identify. THEN add your desired output that exactly matches the sample data after it goes through the transformation you are wanting to do it. Right now I see a column that has `aaaa` and the output column that matches is `aaaaaaaa`. Why did it double? What is the logic that you used to decide that it doubles. Ambiguity makes it VERY hard to understand what is supposed to happen.

Comment: Hi Peter, first of all welcome to Stack Overflow. I see you made already quite some effort to improve your question. I still have a couple of questions though. (a) How are your fields separated from one another? Are they tabs, or multiple white-spaces (more then one space)? (b) Do you mean the _fourth_ column is a multiline version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have multi-space as field separator (FS) and trim trailing whitespaces in the input.
Check the following code(save as ip.awk)

```
BEGIN{
    FS="[[:space:]][[:space:]]+";
    op[0] = "";
    line  = 0;
}
{
    if(NR <= 1 || NF == 0)
        skip;
    if(NF==5)
    {
        line = line + 1;
        op[line,"1"] = $1;
        op[line,"2"] = $2;
        op[line,"3"] = $3;
        op[line,"4"] = $4;
        op[line,"5"] = $5;
    }
    else{
        #printf("line:%d,tok=%s,ex=%s\n",line,$2,op[line,"4"]);
        op[line,"4"] = op[line,"4"] " " $2;
    }
}
END{
OFS=";"
for(i=1;i<=line;i++)
    print op[i,"1"],op[i,"2"],op[i,"3"],op[i,"4"],op[i,"5"];
}
```

You can run the code like this
**1.txt is the input file**

```
cat 1.txt | sed 's/[ \t]*$//g' | awk -f ip.awk
```

OP is

```
Date;AMOUNT;OP;DESCRIPTION;CODE
12/10/2018;$123,45;id01;payment for hotel in Las Vegas room room service dinner golf club ;005214875462
12/11/2018;$400,00;id04;cash from ATM located in L.A.;0528158852687
12/12/2018;$1000,00;id99;ACME tornado pill ;854674852658
```

Comment: Shorter than mine and beautiful ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl one-liner

```
> cat tomc_in.dat
Date    AMOUNT  OP  DESCRIPTION CODE
12/10/2018  $123,45 id01    payment for hotel in Las Vegas  005214875462
                              room
                              room service
                              dinner
                              golf club
12/11/2018  $400,00 id04    cash from ATM   0528158852687
                                 located in L.A.
12/12/2018  $1000,00    id99    ACME tornado pill   854674852658
> perl -F"/\s+/" -lane ' print $all if $idp and /^\d+/ and $idp ne $F[2] ;if($.>1) { if(/^\d+/) { $p="$F[0];$F[1];$F[2]";$c=$F[-1];$de=join(" ",@F[3..$#F-1]);$idp=$F[2]} else {s/^\s*|\s*$//g;$de.=" ".$_}; $all="$p;$de;$c"; } END { print $all } ' tomc_in.dat
12/10/2018;$123,45;id01;payment for hotel in Las Vegas room room service dinner golf club;005214875462
12/11/2018;$400,00;id04;cash from ATM located in L.A.;0528158852687
12/12/2018;$1000,00;id99;ACME tornado pill;854674852658
>
```

Comment: I like the idea of a "one-liner" where you need to scroll!

Comment: @kvantour.. as long as you dont do vertical scrolling... it is still one-liner.. of course, it is lengthy!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS = ";" }
(NR==1) || !NF { next }
/^[[:space:]]/ {
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")
    desc = desc " " $0
    next
}
NR > 2 { print bef, desc, aft }
{
    bef = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3
    aft = $NF
    gsub(/^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){3}|[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*$/,"")
    desc = $0
}
END { print bef, desc, aft }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
12/10/2018;$123,45;id01;payment for hotel in Las Vegas room room service dinner golf club;005214875462
12/11/2018;$400,00;id04;cash from ATM located in L.A.;0528158852687
12/12/2018;$1000,00;id99;ACME tornado pill;854674852658
```

The above will retain white space within the descriptions in case that matters.

Answer (score 0):

**INPUT:**

```
$ cat input.dat
Date         AMOUNT      OP     DESCRIPTION                                 CODE
12/10/2018   $123,45    id01   payment for hotel in Las Vegas            005214875462     
                              room
                              room service
                              dinner
                              golf club

12/11/2018   $400,00    id04    cash from ATM                            0528158852687
                                 located in L.A.
12/12/2018   $1000,00   id99    ACME tornado pill                         854674852658
```

**Command:**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=";"}/^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/{if(NR>2){print date,amount,desc, op}date=$1; amount=$2; op=$3; code=$NF; for(i=4;i<=NF-1;i++){if(i==4){desc=$i}else{desc=desc" "$i}};next}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){desc=desc" "$i}}END{print date,amount,desc, op}' input.dat
```

**Output:**

```
Date;AMOUNT;OP;DESCRIPTION;CODE
12/10/2018;$123,45;payment for hotel in Las Vegas room room service dinner golf club;id01
12/11/2018;$400,00;cash from ATM located in L.A.;id04
12/12/2018;$1000,00;ACME tornado pill;id99
```

**Explanations:**

- `BEGIN{OFS=";"; print "Date;AMOUNT;OP;DESCRIPTION;CODE"}` set the ouput field separator to `;` and print the header line
- `/^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/` will identify the lines that start with a date
- `{if(NR>2){print date,amount,desc, op}` if we are not currently at the first data line we print the content of the variable that are you used to do the data transformation
- `date=$1; amount=$2; op=$3; code=$NF; for(i=4;i<=NF-1;i++){if(i==4){desc=$i}else{desc=desc" "$i}};next` Save the input data fields in variables and generate the desc variable by appending all the field until the one before the code and jump to next line
- When we reach a line that does not start with a date, `{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){desc=desc" "$i}}` append everything to the description
- `END{print date,amount,desc, op}` print the last line

  ```
  # gawk profile, created Wed Dec 12 17:34:39 2018
  # BEGIN rule(s)

  BEGIN {
         OFS = ";"
         print "Date;AMOUNT;OP;DESCRIPTION;CODE"
  }

  # Rule(s)

  /^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/ { 
         if (NR > 2) { 
                 print date, amount, desc, op
          }
         date = $1
         amount = $2
         op = $3
         code = $NF
         for (i = 4; i <= NF - 1; i++) {
                if (i == 4) { 
                         desc = $i
                 } else {
                         desc = desc " " $i
                  }
          }
         next
  }

  {
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
                desc = desc " " $i
          }
  }

  # END rule(s)

  END {
         print date, amount, desc, op
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I decided you input file is tab separated
and that you are getting commas between descriptions on different lines.
(because I did not like seeing " ... room room service  ... " )

Your sample data

```
cat input; 
Date    AMOUNT  OP  DESCRIPTION CODE
12/10/2018  $123,45 id01    payment for hotel in Las Vegas  005214875462
                              room
                              room service
                              dinner
                              golf club
12/11/2018  $400,00 id04    cash from ATM   0528158852687
                                 located in L.A.
12/12/2018  $1000,00    id99    ACME tornado pill   854674852658
```

My script

```
cat collapse_column.awk
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
# collapse_column.awk

BEGIN{FS="\t"; OFS=";"; getline}
/^[0-9]/{
    if(Date){
        print Date,AMOUNT,OP,DESCRIPTION,CODE;
    }
    Date=$1;AMOUNT=$2;OP=$3;DESCRIPTION=$4;CODE=$5
}

/^[^0-9]/{
    gsub(/ [[:space:]]+/, ",")
    DESCRIPTION = DESCRIPTION $0
}
END{print Date,AMOUNT,OP,DESCRIPTION,CODE}
```

The result

```
$ ./collapse_column.awk input 
12/10/2018;$123,45;id01;payment for hotel in Las Vegas,room,room service,dinner,golf club;005214875462
12/11/2018;$400,00;id04;cash from ATM,located in L.A.;0528158852687
12/12/2018;$1000,00;id99;ACME tornado pill;854674852658
```

the awk script is recognizing full rows that begin with a digit and assign the fields to variables
lines which do not begin with a digit are assumed to be continuations of the previous row and trimmed values accumulated. when a new full row is found the previous full row along with any accumulated items is output